# VSTO problem - cannot create visual studio excel workbook project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007

When I try to create a Excel 2007 Workbook project, in Visual Studio 2008, I get the following errormessage:

> Project cannot be created because the "Excel Visual Studio Design-Time Adaptor Add-in" is not working correctly. Excel might have disabled the add-in or made it inactive, or all add-ins might be disabled in your Trust Center settings. Check the add-in status in Excel Options. If the add-in is active and enabled, reinstall or repair Visual Studio Tools for Office.

I have verified that the add-in is not inactive or disabled and I have tried to repair and uninstall/reinstall VSTO several times.

What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you haven't checked the trust settings, this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386131.aspx) describes how to.

I came across this on a MSDN forum:

> For the repair to work, you'll have to
>   run the VS Command Prompt with Admin
>   Priviledges (right click, run as
>   administrator). Then run this command
>   line:
>
> C:>AddinUtil
>   -AddInRoot:"%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   Shared\VSTA\AppInfoDocument" -Rebuild
>
> If it still doesn't work, you may also
>   have a corrupt pipleline store, which
>   can be fixed like this:
>
> C:>AddinUtil
>   -PipelineRoot:"%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   Shared\VSTA\Pipeline" -Rebuild
>
> You'll get one warning from that
>   command but that is expected.

Failing that, I think you will have to run a repair on the Visual Studio 2008 installation (put the installation DVD in a drive, and select the repair option).

Answer (score 0):

I'd set Excel 2003 to open XLS files by default. I saw the same error message you got until I repaired Office 2007 from the Add/Remove Programs menu.