# VSTO: Can't create workbooks

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsto

When I try to create a Excel or Word workbook project in VS, I get the message:

> A compatible version of Microsoft
>   Office is not installed on this
>   computer.  You must install the
>   version of Office that is compatible
>   with your project.  In addition,
>   repair the version of the Visual
>   Studio Tools for Office runtime  that
>   is appropriate for your project by
>   running the installation program and 
>   selecting the Repair option. The
>   runtime is available at the Microsoft 
>   Download Center.

I have VS 2008 and Office 2003 Professional SP 3 installed. I did a full install of Office, 
and it looks like the Interop DLLs are in the GAC. I am creating an Office 2003 project. I tried the steps from [VSTO problem - cannot create visual studio excel workbook project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274653/vsto-problem-cannot-create-visual-studio-excel-workbook-project). I repaired VS 2008 from the disk after installing Office 2003 Pro. I had Office 2003 Standard installed earlier, but I removed it before installing Office 2003 Pro. I am able to create add-ins. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you formally have a non-"complete" install of MS Office? or a non-Professional version?

Comment: Yes,see the end of the question.

Comment: meh, teach me not to read properly :( that's likely your issue, i've posted a possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps worked:

1) Unistall Office Pro, reboot and reinstall.

2) Repair VS 2008 from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2k3 Standard is not compatible with VSTO; upgrading from 2k3 standard has likely left something in your registry.

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3f12200d-f685-4bc9-bff0-d380067f515a) suggests that even moving to 2k7 doesn't give compatibility in this case!  How about creating a new user profile?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same prob but I installed office2003 sp3 and now its working fine